# How can I get rid of trailing slash for index.html

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, trailing-slash

How do I get rid of the trailing slash on my site?

For example, I have an **index.html** at

```
 http://example.com/examplepage/index.html
```

Instead of

```
 http://example.com/examplepage/
```

I would like the URL to be

```
 http://example.com/examplepage
```

Could I do this with .htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

The trailing slash is really important for apache, without it, even if you have an `index.html` sitting in the `examplepage` folder, people will be able to see the contents of your folders. Apache deals with this by having a module loaded by default that redirects the browser to include the trailing slash everytime a directory/folder is accessed. You can turn that off but it's noted in the documentation that [there's a major security concern](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) when you do that; mainly, the contents of your folders can be viewed regardless of having an index file or not.

So you can turn this off, but you probably want to still have the trailing slash at least internally. You can do that with mod_rewrite:

```
# turn off the mechanism to always redirect to the trailing slash
DirectorySlash Off

# Internally add the trailing slash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond $1 .*[^/]$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L]
```

That should allow you to access `http://example.com/examplepage` without getting redirected to `http://example.com/examplepage/`.

Comment: Huh. Still the same as what I tried before. Thanks, though.